# ArrayList : 2 Methods to calculate average and sum

Tags: java

I am stuck about an exercise: In fact, I have to create 2 methods: addition() and average() via an ArrayList.

```
int[] tab = {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println("4) Average : " + average(tab));
```

My first addition() method is correct:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> addition(int[] tab){
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

      int sum = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++){
         sum+= tab[i];
      }

      list.add(sum);
      return list;
}
```

Then, I have to use my addition() method into my average() method, but I am stuck.
Here is an idea of my average() method.

```
public static ArrayList<Double> average(int[] tab){
//ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
//  return (double) addition(tab) / tab.length;
}
```

I thank you in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried your idea?

Comment: @Scott Hunter: I don't know how to create my average() method via my addition() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `double` to the `list` by calling `.get(0)` to get the sum which should be at position 0, and `return` the average:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> average(int[] tab){
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add((double) addition(tab).get(0) / tab.length);
    return list;
}
```

Also you need to print this out using `.get(0)` as well to get the first value of this `List`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] tab = {1,2,3,4};
    System.out.println("4) Average : " + average(tab).get(0));
}
```

However, I doubt the way this was set up in general, though this *works* it should not be done this way as you are using `List`s that only contain a single value.  Why use a `List` then?  To me it seems the problem statement requires you to use a `List` as a *parameter*, not as a *return* type.

The modified way of doing this is much cleaner can be seen below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> tab = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
    System.out.println("4) Average : " + average(tab));
}


public static int addition(ArrayList<Integer> list){
      int sum = 0;
      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
         sum+= list.get(i);
      }
      return sum;
}

public static double average(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    return (double) addition(list) / list.size();
}
```

Here you can see how simple the `average` method becomes, and now you can simply find the average by calling `average(tab)`, instead of needing to call `.get(0)` on it.

Comment: Ohhh!! Thank you a lot Nexevis it's OK now... Thank you for your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your addition() method should return an int (or a double) value rather than a List.
Then, your average() implementation would simply return (double)addition(tab) / tab.length

Answer (score 1):

Other than skipping a few steps, your guess seems right for average...  if `addition()` returns a list, you need to get the first element fo the list...  and if `average()` returns a list, you need to return the list...  you also may need to cast both sides of the division (not sure it's necessary, but won't hurt).

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(1);
Double average = (Double)addition(tab).get(0) / (Double)tab.length;
list.add(average);
return list;
```

Comment: But yes, I agree with others that your methods should return `Integer` and `Double`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I think you should solve the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] tab = {1,2,3,4};

    System.out.println(addition(tab));
    System.out.println(average(tab));

}

public static int addition(int[] tab){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<tab.length;i++) {
        sum += tab[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static double average(int[] tab){
    int total = addition(tab);
    return total / tab.length;
}
```

Comment: The question states "via `ArrayList`", but you don't use `ArrayList` at all.

Comment: Yes, this is why I said this is how I should think you should solve the problem because I think with the array list could also be ment the numbers which are passed into the function, which are replaced with the array he is using.